# Get placeholder index for jQueryUI Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, pagination, jquery-ui-sortable

I use jQuery Sortable plugin for sorting a list of pages. Users can rearrange the pages in custom order. However, I want the placeholder box to contain the page number the page will get on release.

If the user has three pages in their list, and rearranges the second page, to the end, the placeholder for page three would show the number three.

How would I go about to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display index of list item using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442862/display-index-of-list-item-using-jquery)

Comment: No, I want to get the feedback while sorting, not after sorting is finished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
      placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight ui-sort-position',
      helper: 'clone',
      sort: function(e,ui) {
         $(ui.placeholder).html(Number($("#sortable > li:visible").index(ui.placeholder)+1));
      }
});​
```

will show you the new index (+1) ... [working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/dQjr5/1/)

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much :) I manage to get the correct index as well with the following code: `$(this).find('li:not(.ui-sortable-helper)').index(ui.placeholder) + 1` - I don't know what's most logic?

Comment: @rebellion which ever works for you - if you prefer you method then add an answer and accept that - or accept my answer ... please remember to go back and accept answers to the questions you have asked

Comment: One more thing. My users are allowed to remove elements dynamically from the list. The counter will then show ie. [ 1 | 2 | 4 ] if item 3 is deleted. Do you know how I can refresh the count upon deletion?

Comment: @rebellion how are you "deleting" them from the list ? if you actually remove the DOM element the index should refresh automatically

Comment: @rebellion works for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/dQjr5/2/ click "remove" to remove them

Comment: Thanks @ManseUK, I've just overlooked the fact that the elements weren't actually removed from the list, just faded out :)